Outlook add in for mobile on message send
Is there a way to create an add-ins for outlook web/mobile that triggers an action/confirmation when clicking send?
i've tried to read and apply microsoft documentation for outlook add ins but it states that it supports message read only

Please add a few more details and examples of what you have already tried yourself. It will help us understand the issue better so you'll get better answers.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i want to trigger a confirmation window when the user click send on outlook mobile and web

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=modern and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/onmessagesend-onappointmentsend-events?tabs=web
